# What implementation version of JSF that bundle with Glassfish 3.0.1

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I am trying to find out what implementation version of JSF that bundle with Glassfish 3.0.1. Is it Mojarra 2.0.2 or 2.0.3

Here http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.0.1-final.html, it only tell me that it is JSF 2.0 but not sure what implementation is it.

I remember you can find out about that information by writing 1-2 simple line of codes, but I forgot. I am using Java-EE 6 BTW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 2.0.2. You can replace it with a download of 2.0.3 or even 2.1.0-RC (don't forget to clean the cache).

```
FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

Comment: I will try 2.0.3 for now. Not a big fan of RC. Thank you